# L10N Support for Bootstrap Datetimepicker in Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, localization

When using the datetimepicker of Bootstrap in a Django form, the language and date format can be set like this

```
$(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'de',
            format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'
      });
});
```

Is there an elegant way to automatically fill in these two parameters so that changing the language code in Django will change the locale and format for the datetimepicker accordingly?